# Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/rab/input

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, bigdata

Following is the output of my job ... on single mode it runs well but on pseudo distribute mode it throws the following error all the time... I have tried a lot but could not meet a possible solution from anyone yet. I need a quick fix of the problem.

Highly obliged upon success...

```
rab@rab-VirtualBox:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
17/03/17 22:13:12 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
17/03/17 22:13:12 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
17/03/17 22:13:12 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hadoop-rab/mapred/staging/rab/.staging/job_201703172201_0004
17/03/17 22:13:12 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:rab cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/rab/input
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/rab/input
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:197)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:1081)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1073)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:983)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1353)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep.run(Grep.java:69)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep.main(Grep.java:93)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

Comment: i run the follwoing command              rab@rab-VirtualBox:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'

Comment: use 8021 as the hdfs port

Comment: For any question asking for help with an error, you need an [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

The log output shows error:

"org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: **hdfs:**//localhost:9000/user/rab/input"

1. Do you have a directory called "input" under /user/rab on the HDFS file system? The error indicates that you don't ! The error also shows that it is looking at hdfs and not the local file system. You can check with the following command

   "hdfs dfs -ls /user/rab"
2. The full command that you used "bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'" expects the command to be of the form "hadoop jar jarfilename classname hdfsinputdirectory hdfsoutputdirectory" where classname is the name of the class in the jar file that you want to run.